Numpy 3rd order error when calculating a line
I needed a simple x^3 function, and went about making a line.
I attempted using x = np.arange(0, 2001, 100); x**3.
My answer shows the output:
array([          0,     1000000,     8000000,    27000000,    64000000,
         125000000,   216000000,   343000000,   512000000,   729000000,
        1000000000,  1331000000,  1728000000, -2097967296, -1550967296,
        -919967296,  -198967296,   618032704,  1537032704, -1730934592,
        -589934592])

Oddly, when I change the line to np.array(np.arange(0, 2001, 100)/1000)**3*1000**3, I get the expected output:
array([0.000e+00, 1.000e+06, 8.000e+06, 2.700e+07, 6.400e+07, 1.250e+08,
       2.160e+08, 3.430e+08, 5.120e+08, 7.290e+08, 1.000e+09, 1.331e+09,
       1.728e+09, 2.197e+09, 2.744e+09, 3.375e+09, 4.096e+09, 4.913e+09,
       5.832e+09, 6.859e+09, 8.000e+09])

I cannot seem to debug why the difference in outcomes arises.
My full code sequence follows here:
from pandas import DataFrame as DF

def func_x3(_line=np.arange(0, 2001, 100)):
    return _line, np.array([x**3 for x in _line])

_x3, _y3 = func_x3(); a_line = DF(_x3, index=_y3)  

I have tried variations of this, but none seem to work as expected.
This does not occur when manipulating smaller values, say func_x3(_f=2.001, _st=.1).
It also does not occur when I attempt doing other power functions:
def func_x2(_i=0, _f=2001, _st=100):
    _line = np.arange(_i, _f, _st)
    return _line, _line**2 #(1/2)

_x2, _y2 = func_x2(); a_line2 = DF(_x2, index=_y2)


This does not occur when manipulating smaller values, say func_x3(_f=2.001, _st=.1).

can you please edit your question with new information

The problem is that np.arange(0, 2001, 100) creates an integer array, since all the elements are integers.  Depending on your machine, the elements are either np.int32 or np.int64.
When you cube an array, numpy makes the elements of your resulting array be the same type as the initial array.  If you're on a machine that happens to use np.int32, then 1900 ** 3 overflows 32-bits.
You need to force arange to use floats.  np.arange(0, 2001.0, 100) is all you need to get the answers you want.

That makes perfect sense why smaller values would work. I intuited that the values had to be too big to process, but clueless to know exactly why that would be the case. I am not particularly sure how to debug this and find out that numpy has reached this boundary. This may be surplus to my needs now that I know the limitations of the system. In looking at the correct matrix, anything over 9 digits exceeds the 32-bit threshold like you said, so that would be a start to a test function. I'm thankful for the help.
